# DRF: Dynamically select Serializer class based on field value

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working in an application where I need to build an API to return product catalogs to the application's client, this is how my models look.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.IntegerField(...)
    description = models.CharField(...)
    category_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(...)
    .  
    .  
    .  

class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField(...)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, ..)
    .  
    # Common product fields
    .  

class ProductA(Product):
    product_a_field = models.IntegerField(..)
    .  
    .  
    .  

class ProductB(Product):
    product_b_field = models.IntegerField(...)
    .  
    .  
    .
```

Except for the common fields (inheritated from `Product`) both models ProductA and ProductB are very different from each other.
What I want to do is to send a different set of products to the clients based on the value of the `Category.category_type` field.

I would like to simplify my Category Serializer as:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        .
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #
        # Some code to select the product Serializer
        #

    products = ProductSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'category_type', 'products')
```

Is there any way to achieve this? I'm using Python3, Django 1.10, and DRF 3.6.

Comment: Added a possible way to access category_type. Again, without more details it's hard to say what you need

Answer (score 4):

Override the [get_serializer_class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself) method in an APIView.

Then access the request and do your logic there:

```
#taken directly from the docs for generic APIViews
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.user.is_staff:
        return FullAccountSerializer
    return BasicAccountSerializer
```

Also, you can access the `category_type` variable like this in your class based view:

```
@property
def category_type(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_category_tpye'):
        self._category_type = Category.objects.get(attribute=self.kwargs['attribute'])
    return self._category_type
```

Comment: Does the APIView have access to the instance? I would need to check against an instance attribute.

Comment: @LuisAlbertoSantana the view has access to the serializers which then access the instance, or the queryset which obviously should be associated to your target model. I think you're trying to ask how you would access the `category_type` field. If that's the case then you would get that data from the request. In other words the client would select and send data in the request that you can use to identify the model/serizlalizer type.

Comment: @LuisAlbertoSantana if the data isn't coming from the request then you can infer it from the api endpoint the client is sending the request to, without knowing more details the best I can do is guess your specific use case